# Spring mvc foreign field in table won't update

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I have 2 models with the ff columns in the db:

```
ContractHeader
id = primary key
con_num

ContractEntitlement
id = primary key
ch_id = foreign key to id in ContractHeader table
category
```

One contract header can have multiple contract entitlement.  Model classes are:

ContractHeader.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTRACT_HEADER")
public class ContractHeader {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contractHeader")
    private List<ContractEntitlement> contractEntitlements;

    @Column(name = "con_num")
    private String conNum;
    getter and setter ....
```

ContractEntitlement

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTRACT_ENTITLEMENT")
public class ContractEntitlement {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ch_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ContractHeader contractHeader; 

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

   getter and setter ....
```

When I save the date from jsp it properly inserts the value with no errors from each table in spring but the ch_id field (foreign_key) is always empty.  Any idea why ch_is in not being populated by the id from contractheader table?

Comment: Do you want ch_id to be populated automatically or you are sending value for ch_id from form and still it is inserting null for it?

Comment: the id from contract header is populated after being saved from table (serialized).   I was assuming that mapping the id to ch_id will auto populate the ch_id in the table.  I don't send the ch_id from the form.

Comment: The more I think about it I guess this needs to be done on db side (store procedured).  Any comments?

Comment: Yes @Arnold, you need to handle this situation on DB side, as Spring will not be able to identify which id needs to be populated in ch_id.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to the question but more of a workaround and want to share.  Instead of processing in db side I get the id before the session closes after it is saved:

```
public String addContractHeader(@Validated @ModelAttribute("contractHeader") ContractHeader p, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    System.out.println("BEFORE " + p.getId());
    this.contractHeaderService.addContractHeader(p);
    System.out.println("AFTER " + p.getId());
    for (Iterator<ContractEntitlement> i = p.getContractEntitlements().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        ContractEntitlement employee = i.next();
        -- use p.getId() to store in ch_id (foreign_key)
        this.contractEntitlementService.addContractEntitlement(employee);

    }

BEFORE 0
Hibernate: insert into CONTRACT_HEADER (contact_email, contact_number, contact_person, contract_number, contract_package, contract_status, contract_sum, contract_type, currency_type, customer_address, customer_name, expiry_date, package_other, remarks, start_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Info: INFO : com.at.ccts.dao.ContractHeaderDAOImpl - ContractHeader saved successfully, ContractHeader Details=com.at.ccts.model.ContractHeader@39d1a603
2017-05-01T20:01:52.537+0800|Info:
AFTER 19
```

I got the id stored in the db (serialized).